# string with values selection based on values

Tags: python, list, selection

I have a set with 2 values

```
list = [('coin unit', 9.0), ('normal margin requirements', 8.5), ('futures industry', 8.2), ('wild cryptocurrency market', 7.333333333333334), ('biggest financial institutions', 6.833333333333334), ('futures market', 1.0), ('biggest banks', 0.5), ('cryptocurrency frenzy', 0.5)]
```

how can I keep only those values that have score bigger than 1?

Comment: Use a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) `l = [(a, b) for a, b in l if b > 1]`

Comment: Thank @PatrickHaugh! Didn't know the term for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_of_stuff = [('coin unit', 9.0), ('normal margin requirements', 8.5), ('futures industry', 8.2), ('wild cryptocurrency market', 7.333333333333334), ('biggest financial institutions', 6.833333333333334), ('futures market', 1.0), ('biggest banks', 0.5), ('cryptocurrency frenzy', 0.5)]
newlist = [x for x in list_of_stuff if x[1] > 1.0]
print newlist
```

will result in

```
[('coin unit', 9.0), ('normal margin requirements', 8.5), ('futures industry', 8.2), ('wild cryptocurrency market', 7.333333333333334), ('biggest financial institutions', 6.833333333333334)]
```

Answer (score 0):

> **What about without loop :**

```
list_1 = [('coin unit', 9.0), ('normal margin requirements', 8.5), ('futures industry', 8.2), ('wild cryptocurrency market', 7.333333333333334), ('biggest financial institutions', 6.833333333333334), ('futures market', 1.0), ('biggest banks', 0.5), ('cryptocurrency frenzy', 0.5)]

print(list(filter(lambda x:x[1]>1,list_1)))
```

output:

```
[('coin unit', 9.0), ('normal margin requirements', 8.5), ('futures industry', 8.2), ('wild cryptocurrency market', 7.333333333333334), ('biggest financial institutions', 6.833333333333334)]
```

P.S : never use `list` as a variable name because list is a keyword in python.

Comment: I agree but I was using his variables, should have fixed it... and done that :-)